# Play Streaming URL in NotificationService in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, unnotificationserviceextension

I have played video in notification service extension by saving in the disk. Now I want to play streaming URL in notification service extension as an attachment. I have tried directly passing URL as an attachment, but it returns nil in the variable `attach1`.

**Below is my code:**

```
import UserNotifications
import UIKit

class NotificationService: UNNotificationServiceExtension {

    var contentHandler: ((UNNotificationContent) -> Void)?
    var bestAttemptContent: UNMutableNotificationContent?

    override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {
        self.contentHandler = contentHandler
        bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)

        //Media
        func failEarly() {
            contentHandler(request.content)
        }

        guard let content = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent) else {
            return failEarly()
        }

        guard let attachmentURL = content.userInfo["attachment_url"] as? String, let url = URL(string: attachmentURL) else {
            return failEarly()
        }

        // Saving streaming url video
        var attach1 : UNNotificationAttachment?
        do {
        attach1 = try UNNotificationAttachment(identifier: request.content.categoryIdentifier, url: url, options: nil)
        } catch {
            failEarly()
        }    

        content.attachments = [attach1] as! [UNNotificationAttachment]
        contentHandler(content.copy() as! UNNotificationContent)
    }

    override func serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire() {
        // Called just before the extension will be terminated by the system.
        // Use this as an opportunity to deliver your "best attempt" at modified content, otherwise the original push payload will be used.
        if let contentHandler = contentHandler, let bestAttemptContent =  bestAttemptContent {
            contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
        }
    }

}
```

My Streaming URL is from [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eudBrBuNABA).

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are some scenarios you must need to know.

1. If you are using content extension that time `category` must be same as declare in `Info.plist` file of `UNNotificationContentExtension`.
2. `UserNotificationAttachment` can't store data url. i.e. it must contains fileUrl which is url of file downloaded in `UNNotificationServiceExtension` and return in completion.

So, your following code is totally wrong.

```
var attach1 : UNNotificationAttachment?
do {
    attach1 = try UNNotificationAttachment(identifier: request.content.categoryIdentifier, url: url, options: nil)
} catch {
    failEarly()
}
```

I'm not sure but, youtube video url link can't play in `AVPlayer`, there should be extension of video in url required when use with `AVPlayer`.

Check the all the things properly. See [UNNotificationServiceExtension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension) & [UNNotificationContentExtension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotificationsui/unnotificationcontentextension) for more info.